# AngularJS Change Checked Value of Radio Button Using $scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I am editing User Form. I send the data from controller to the edit view using `$scope` object for editing form. The data is look like this:

```
        $scope.changeUser = [

          {

                id: 1,
                username: 'Ramesh',
                password: 'Ramesh1@23',
                role: 'admin',
                active: 'no'
            }
    ];
       <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Action</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="radio-list">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2"  data-ng-model="changeUser.active"  value="yes"/>
                                    Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" data-ng-model="changerUser.active" value="no"/>
                                    No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

When edit form get `{{changeUser.action}}` than, I have to checked the radio button accordingly. As like when `action=='no'` the radio button with name `no` should be automatically checked as we did using `checked value=no` in the html. I have to write the ng-if conditions seeing the action value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the index of `changeUser` array in your `ng-model`.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Action</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio-list">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" data-ng-model="changeUser[0].active" value="yes" />
                    Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" data-ng-model="changeUser[0].active" value="no" />
                    No
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

**[See the Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hVg13SsjYhaVIiILcpBD?p=preview)**

Comment: This is not the answer i am looking for. I am asking about doing `checked value=no` or `checked value=yes` according to the  value get from `@scope`  `action: yes or no'.

Comment: @user3789184 The above solution will work. Since the angular will compare the value of 'ng-model' with the value assigned to radio. If matched the respective radio will be shown checked.

Comment: But, When i edit the form, only one data will be on `$scope`. So, that, I cannot use `ng-repeat` in this case.

Comment: If you don't want to use ng-repeat, remove 1st div and pass the data-ng-model as **changeUser[0].active** to both the radio inputs.

Comment: @user3789184 Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: I am still getting no checked value as i did same as yours. When i run `{{changeUser.active}} = 'no'`  value but unable to checked `no`.

Comment: @user3789184 **chaneUser[0].active** not chaneUser.active

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96250/discussion-between-user3789184-and-vvk).